# How am i incorrectly using SubsetRandomSampler?

Tags: pytorch, tensor

I have a custom defined dataset:
rcvdataset =  rcvLSTMDataSet('foo.csv', 'foolabels.csv')

I also define the following:

````
batch_size = 50
validation_split = .2
shuffle_rcvdataset = True
random_seed= 42


```
rcvdataset_size = len(rcvdataset)
indices = list(range(rcvdataset_size))
split = int(np.floor(validation_split * rcvdataset_size))
if shuffle_rcvdataset :
    np.random.seed(random_seed)
    np.random.shuffle(indices)
train_indices, val_indices = indices[split:], indices[:split]


train_sampler = SubsetRandomSampler(train_indices)
test_sampler = SubsetRandomSampler(val_indices)

train_loader = torch.utils.data.DataLoader(rcvdataset, batch_size=batch_size, 
                                           sampler=train_sampler)
test_loader = torch.utils.data.DataLoader(rcvdataset, batch_size=batch_size,
                                                sampler=test_sampler)
```
````

using this training call:

````
```
def train(dataloader, model, loss_fn, optimizer):
    size = len(dataloader.dataset)
    model.train()
    for batch, (X, y) in enumerate(dataloader):
        X, y = X.to(device), y.to(device)

        # Compute prediction error
        pred = model(X)
        loss = loss_fn(pred, y)

        # Backpropagation
        optimizer.zero_grad()
        loss.backward()
        optimizer.step()

        if batch % 100 == 0:
            loss, current = loss.item(), batch * len(X)
            print(f"loss: {loss:>7f}  [{current:>5d}/{size:>5d}]")
```
````

But when i try to run it, i get:

```
    Epoch 1
    -------------------------------
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "lstmTrainer.py", line 94, in <module>
        train(train_sampler, model, loss_fn, optimizer)
      File "lstmTrainer.py", line 58, in train
        size = len(dataloader.dataset)
    AttributeError: 'SubsetRandomSampler' object has no attribute 'dataset'
```

If i instead load the dataset indirectly with:

```
    train(train_loader, model, loss_fn, optimizer)
```

it tells me:

```
    TypeError: default_collate: batch must contain tensors, numpy arrays, numbers, dicts or lists; found <class 'pandas.core.series.Series'>
```

I'm not clear on what the first error is, at all.  Is the second error trying to tell me that somewhere in my dataset, something isn't a tensor?

Thank you.

As requested, here is rcvDataSet.py:

```
from __future__ import print_function, division
import os
import torch
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from torch.utils.data import Dataset, DataLoader
class rcvLSTMDataSet(Dataset):
    """rcv dataset."""
    TIMESTEPS = 10

    def __init__(self, csv_data_file, annotations_file):
        """
        Args:
            csv_data_file (string): Path to the csv file with the training data
            annotations_file (string): Path to the file with the annotations
            
        """
        
        self.csv_data_file = csv_data_file
        self.annotations_file = annotations_file
        self.labels = pd.read_csv(annotations_file)
        self.data = pd.read_csv(csv_data_file)
        

    def __len__(self):
        return len(self.labels)

    def __getitem__(self, idx):
        """
        pytorch expects whatever data is returned is in the form of a tensor.  Included, it expects the label for the data.
        Together, they make a tuple.          
        """
        
        # convert every ten indexes and label into one observation
        Observation = []
        counter = 0
        start_pos = self.TIMESTEPS *idx
        avg_1 = 0
        avg_2 = 0
        avg_3 = 0
        while counter < self.TIMESTEPS:
            Observation.append(self.data.iloc[idx + counter])            
            avg_1 += self.labels.iloc[idx + counter][2]
            avg_2 += self.labels.iloc[idx + counter][1]
            avg_3 += self.labels.iloc[idx + counter][0]
            counter += 1        
        
        avg_1 = avg_1 / self.TIMESTEPS
        avg_2 = avg_2 / self.TIMESTEPS
        avg_3 = avg_3 / self.TIMESTEPS
        current_labels = [avg_1, avg_2, avg_3]
        print(current_labels)
        return Observation, current_labels
        

def main():
        loader = rcvLSTMDataSet('foo1.csv','foo2.csv')
        j = 0
        while j < len(loader.data % loader.TIMESTEPS):
            print(loader.__getitem__(j))
            j += 1

if "__main__" == __name__:
    main()
```

Comment: I think you should put all your codes here because there are missing parts to understand your code.

Comment: Could you please add the code of `rcvLSTMDataSet` class?

Comment: Done, see above

Comment: Try print(train_loader) and what is the output?

Comment: comes back with:  <torch.utils.data.dataloader.DataLoader object at 0x000002390990D700>

Comment: Perfect, dataloader is correct. Now try to print(len(train_loader.dataset))  directly after the line of defining train_loader.

Comment: 382487  -- an integer number that agrees with the length of the csv

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Cause:** If you look to the error message, you will find that you call train function like that:

```
train(train_sampler, model, loss_fn, optimizer)
```

This is not correct, you should call train() with `train_loader`  not with `train_sampler`.

**Solution:** you should correct it to:

```
train(train_loader, model, loss_fn, optimizer)
```

**Error message:**

```
 Epoch 1
    -------------------------------
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "lstmTrainer.py", line 94, in <module>
        train(train_sampler, model, loss_fn, optimizer)   <------ look here 
      File "lstmTrainer.py", line 58, in train
        size = len(dataloader.dataset)
    AttributeError: 'SubsetRandomSampler' object has no attribute 'dataset'
```

**Second Error message:**

If you look at your Dataset class `rcvLSTMDataSet`, you will find `observations` list append items with `pandas.core.series.Series` type, and it is not a pythonic scalar numbers because you read all columns in your csv file. You should use `.iloc[....].values` instead of `iloc[....]`. By doing this, you will ensure that your list contains `char` or `float` or `int` types  and it can be converted to a tensor smoothly without errors.

**Final remark:**

You can read [here](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/data.html#:%7E:text=Data%20loader.,See%20torch.) about Dataloader and Samplers, I summarized here some points:

> Samplers are used to specify the sequence of indices/keys used in data
> loading.
>
> Data loader combines a dataset and a sampler, and provides an iterable
> over the given dataset.
>
> PyTorch provides two data primitives: `torch.utils.data.DataLoader` and
> `torch.utils.data.Dataset` that allow you to use pre-loaded datasets as
> well as your own data. Dataset stores the samples and their
> corresponding labels, and DataLoader wraps an iterable around the
> Dataset to enable easy access to the samples.

Comment: Read only one column?  I don't follow.   Each frame has several columns.   Each row is one sample, 10 samples is one observation, in my case.  Why would i reduce it to one column?       As to the first one,  if the type is wrong, how does one actually use subsetrandomsampler? I thought the idea was to provide sections of the dataset as their own dataloaders, so it could be trained in batches.  Do i have that wrong?

Comment: Oh  i see.  .values so that the type is correct. okay i get that.  How about the first one?  Am I just misunderstanding how SubsetRandomSampler is supposed to work?  I thought it would return a dataloader object itself, apparently not.

Comment: Your code is correct but you should send train_loader not train_sampler. I add some comments to my answer.

Comment: So how does the sampler actually get used then?  Where should it be?

Comment: When you add your sampler inside the dataloader `torch.utils.data.DataLoader(rcvdataset, batch_size=batch_size, **sampler=train_sampler**)`

Comment: OHHHH . i see now.  I've been blind. Thank you!

Comment: Hhhh, it happens, no worries. You're welcome.